# Does altText for an input box not work the same way as alt for an image regarding alt values?

Tags: html, accessibility

Does altText or alt for an input box not work the same way as alt for an image regarding reading alt values?

Trying to match AODA standards but the reader I'm using reads alt for images but not altText or alt for input fields which I thought did the same thing.

reads properly:

```
<img src="{{distributor_logo}}" alt="{{distributor_logo_title}}">
```

doesn't read properly:

```
<Input
    otherstuff...
    type={"text"}
    altText={altText}
/>
```

Comment: Normally, the alt attribute of `<input>` is only valid and meaningful for type=image, but otherwise works exactly the same way as the alt of `<img>`, and the support is certainly as good as for images. Can you post the actual HTML code generated for your `<Field>` ? It's impossible to say anything with just the current code.

Comment: I'm not sure what a `<field>` element is but a real `<input type="image">` has an `alt` attribute and not `altText`.

Comment: @QuentinC sorry, it creates an input field so really my question should be that. I'll update it. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp Basically I'm wondering if there's a way to make alt be anything outside of image or have something similar for a text question so that I can include info for blind people?

Comment: Alt is only for images. For other types of input, you are maybe looking for the label ? Each input must have its own label telling what's the purpose of the field, given by `<label>` or aria-label/aria-labelledby.

Answer (score 2):

The `alt` attribute provides content to use when an image isn't available, but you don't have an image, you have a text field. It doesn't make sense, nor is it allowed, to use an alt attribute there.

---

See [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element):

> `alt` — Replacement text for use when images are not available

And further down is a table:

> The following table is non-normative and summarizes which of those content attributes, IDL attributes, methods, and events apply to each state:

`alt` only applies to `type="image"`.

---

The [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) reports:

> Attribute alt not allowed on element input at this point.

---

The purpose of an `input type="text` element is to let the user enter some text. Screen readers are quiet capable of informing users that there is a text field present.

The trick is to make sure they know what kind of information they are expected to enter. Your example code (presumably because it has been reduced too far) doesn't provide that kind of information for people who *don't* use a screen reader.

The tool to do that is the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) which associates some text with the `input`.

Screen readers are the only tools which make use of `label` elements. e.g. they are also used to increase the clickable area to assign focus to the input for users of mice / trackpads / touchscreens. This is especially useful then the input itself has a small surface area (such as a radio button or checkbox will).

Comment: you are correct. There is nothing to signify that the field is optional for people looking at it but it should mentioned it's optional to those in need of a reader. Lets call it a business decision and not my own idea.

Comment: I was also considering using the label's "for" param but wasn't sure if it was read out

Comment: The "for" attribute is to tell the browser which input the label is for. When a screen reader reaches an input, it will say what type of input it is plus the content of any associated label. Ideally you'll put the "(required)" or "(optional)" text right after the label's text so everyone can find out. But if that's not possible, then you can give the input an aria-required attribute set to true or false.

Comment: and don't be tempted to use placeholder text as a label for the input field. Placeholder text is for example input only.